# How to avoid N+1 query when using model_to_dict

Tags: python, peewee

I'm trying to avoid N+1 issue as described in http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#avoiding-the-n-1-problem but still additional queries are executed.

My model:

```python
from peewee import (SqliteDatabase, Model, BigAutoField, CharField, ForeignKeyField)

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')


class TestModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
        legacy_table_names = False


class TestUser(TestModel):
    id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = CharField()


class Book(TestModel):
    id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = CharField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(TestUser, backref='books')


class Movie(TestModel):
    id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = CharField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(TestUser, backref='movies')


class Tape(TestModel):
    id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = CharField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(TestUser, backref='tapes')
```

And my test:

```python
from peewee import JOIN
from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict
from playhouse.test_utils import count_queries

from test_n_plus_1l import *


def test_should_avoid_n_plus_one_problem():
    db.create_tables([TestUser, Book, Movie, Tape])

    tu = TestUser.create(name='Test')
    Book.create(name='Book1', user_id=tu.id)
    Movie.create(name='Movie1', user_id=tu.id)
    Tape.create(name='Tape1', user_id=tu.id)

    with count_queries() as counter:
        tu = TestUser.select(TestUser, Book, Movie, Tape) \
            .join_from(TestUser, Book, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER) \
            .join_from(TestUser, Movie, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER) \
            .join_from(TestUser, Tape, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER) \
            .where(TestUser.id == tu.id).get()
        model_to_dict(tu, backrefs=True, manytomany=True, max_depth=4)

    assert counter.count == 1
```

And after running it I'm getting assertion error:

`E       assert 4 == 1`

Peewees prints executed sql, so I clearly see that joins were executed, but why peewee executes additional queries:

```
('SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."name", "t2"."id", "t2"."name", "t2"."user_id", "t3"."id", "t3"."name", "t3"."user_id", "t4"."id", "t4"."name", "t4"."user_id" FROM "test_user" AS "t1" LEFT OUTER JOIN "book" AS "t2" ON ("t2"."user_id" = "t1"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "movie" AS "t3" ON ("t3"."user_id" = "t1"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "tape" AS "t4" ON ("t4"."user_id" = "t1"."id") WHERE ("t1"."id" = ?) LIMIT ? OFFSET ?', [1, 1, 0])
('SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."name", "t1"."user_id" FROM "book" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."user_id" = ?)', [1])
('SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."name", "t1"."user_id" FROM "movie" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."user_id" = ?)', [1])
('SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."name", "t1"."user_id" FROM "tape" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."user_id" = ?)', [1])
```

Comment: The problem is that each TestUser may have any number of associated Books, Movies or Tapes. So this is an instance where you may benefit from using the prefetch() helper instead - because of the direction of the foreign-keys. That said, you're best off profiling, as prefetch() may not be any faster than just doing the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each TestUser may have any number of associated Books, Movies or Tapes. So this is an instance where you may benefit from using the [prefetch()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#prefetch) helper instead - because of the direction of the foreign-keys. That said, you're best off profiling, as [prefetch()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#prefetch) may not be any faster than just doing the queries.

Here is an example of using [prefetch()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#prefetch). Note how each user has multiple Tweets and Notes, and each Tweet has multiple Flags -- but we only execute a total of 4 queries:

```
class User(Base):
    name = TextField()

class Tweet(Base):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='tweets')
    content = TextField()

class TweetFlag(Base):
    tweet = ForeignKeyField(Tweet, backref='tweet_flags')
    flag_type = IntegerField()

class Note(Base):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref='notes')
    content = TextField()

db.create_tables([User, Tweet, TweetFlag, Note])

for i in range(10):
    user = User.create(name='user-%s' % i)
    for t in range(10):
        tweet = Tweet.create(user=user, content='%s/tweet-%s' % (user.name, t))
        for f in range(3):
            TweetFlag.create(tweet=tweet, flag_type=f)

    for n in range(5):
        Note.create(user=user, content='%s/note-%s' % (user.name, n))

from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict
from playhouse.test_utils import count_queries


with count_queries() as counter:
    q = User.select().order_by(User.name)
    p = prefetch(q, Tweet, TweetFlag, Note)

    accum = []
    for res in p:
        accum.append(model_to_dict(res, backrefs=True))


print(counter.count)
print(accum[0])
```

Output:

```
4
{'id': 1,                                
 'name': 'user-0',   
 'notes': [{'content': 'user-0/note-0', 'id': 1},       
           {'content': 'user-0/note-1', 'id': 2},       
           {'content': 'user-0/note-2', 'id': 3},                                                              
           {'content': 'user-0/note-3', 'id': 4},
           {'content': 'user-0/note-4', 'id': 5}],
 'tweets': [{'content': 'user-0/tweet-0',               
             'id': 1,                                   
             'tweet_flags': [{'flag_type': 0, 'id': 1},                                                        
                             {'flag_type': 1, 'id': 2},
                             {'flag_type': 2, 'id': 3}]},

...
```